# Ruby Sonar Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

So, I am trying to use https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin to integrate my rspec results and ruby code into sonar. One thing I am not sure about is the sonar-project.properties file.

I was able to get the ruby code on sonar but it doesn’t display the code coverage or the number of rspec tests that ran.

For coverage, I am using https://github.com/fguillen/simplecov-rcov. But I am using bundle so the command I am executing is:

```
bundle exec rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter --out reports/rspec.xml
```

Now this does generate the directory called coverage/rcov, but I am not sure how to pass it into sonar-project.properties

Also, I am not sure about the reports path as well:

```
Eg: sonar.junit.reportsPath=reports
```

I am not sure it should be junit.reportsPath or rspec.reportsPath.

Can somebody please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The various properties supported by this plugin are visible here: https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/godaddy/sonar/ruby/RubyPlugin.java

In your case you need to feed:

```
sonar.simplecovrcov.reportPath
```

Comment: That works, I mean I see the coverage numbers in the jenkins build log, but I still don't see results populated in sonar 5.1.2. Does it show up in Unit Test Coverage or Integration Test Coverage ? or do I need to create a new dashboard ?

Comment: According to the code of this plugin, it loads only coverage data, so they should show up as UT Coverage. Can you share the logs of your analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin above is not needed anymore.

For the code coverage to appear in the Sonar dashboard you have to provide Sonar with the SimpleCov output like this:

```
-Dsonar.ruby.coverage.reportPaths=coverage/.resultset.json
```

And if you want the test count to appear as well, then you have to generate generic Sonar test data when running your tests (see: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/) and send it to Sonar like this:

```
-Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-results.xml
```